# Facebook deep link wrong behavior on Android

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking

I have an Android application already set up deep linking to Facebook. Everything works fine except this weird behavior.

If I click on the post contains list of item like this:
[List items example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DnQ1.png)

It will redirect to my app with the information of item that I clicked. This is what I expected but when I click on the post contains only 1 item like this:
[Single item example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RU8VX.png)

It will open the link with Facebook in-app browser, and I have to click on the Open with 'my app' button in the top right corner of the browser to open this with my app. This is not what I expected.

So can anyone please explain what happened? Did I do something wrong or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook hijacks deep-links forcing them to open in it's browser unless you specify your app. Additionally, facebook wraps the deeplink in its own meta-data url which might make your deeplink unusable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I already specify my app, did everything the document said but it still open the link with it's browser. Like I said above, the example 1 works fine but the example 2 isn't working like the way it should be